# Image quality with html2canvas

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I need the user to upload 2+ images and I need to combine the images into one. For that I am using `html2canvas`, and it works fine, but the quality is too low. My desired quality is ~1200x600, but the current image output is 240x500. How can I get a URL of the image with more pixels?

```js
const Grilla1 = ({ phoneImg }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const { setHeight, setWidth, croppedImage, cropperRef } = useContext(GrillasContext);
  const { agregarAlCarrito, counter } = useContext(CartContext)
  const [imagenes, setImagenes] = useState([]);
  const [imagenSeleccionada, setImagenSeleccionada] = useState(null);
  const [isPopupOpen, setPopupOpen] = useState(false);
  const [escala, setEscala] = useState([1, 1])
  const [translateX, setTranslateX] = useState(0);
  const [translateY, setTranslateY] = useState(0);
  const [combinedImageUrl, setCombinedImageUrl] = useState('');

  const [orderInfo, setOrderInfo] = useState({
    modelo: id,
    url: '',
    precio: 0,
    cantidad: counter,
  });

  const combinedImageRef = useRef(null);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  // This function below contains the html2canvas function
  const obtenerPrecio = async (ProductID) => {
    if (ref.current === null) return;

    html2canvas(ref.current, {
      allowTaint: true,
      useCORS: true,
      scale: 1,
      logging: true,
    }).then((canvas) => {
      const screenshotDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1);
      console.log("URL de la imagen generada:", screenshotDataUrl);
      return screenshotDataUrl;
    }).then((screenshotDataUrl) => {
      setCombinedImageUrl(screenshotDataUrl);
      return screenshotDataUrl;
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error al generar la imagen:", err);
    })

    const docRef = doc(db, "celulares", ProductID);
    const documento = await getDoc(docRef);
    const price = documento.data().price
    const product = {
      name: id,
      img: combinedImageUrl,
      price: price,
      counter: counter,
    }

    setOrderInfo((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      url:combinedImageUrl,
      precio:price
    }));

    if (documento.exists()) {
      agregarAlCarrito(product);
      return price;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Me quiero morir")
    }
  }

  console.log(combinedImageUrl);
  
  // Toggle border
  const TogglePopup = () => {
      setPopupOpen(!isPopupOpen);
  };

  const handleAddImageShow = (cloudData) => {
    setImagenes((prevState) => {
      let newState = [...prevState, cloudData];
      setImagenSeleccionada(newState.length - 1);
      return newState;
    });
  };
  
  // DND
  const handleDrop = (fromIndex, toIndex) => {
    const updatedImages = [...imagenes];
    const [movedImage] = updatedImages.splice(fromIndex, 1);
    updatedImages.splice(toIndex, 0, movedImage);
    setImagenes(updatedImages);
  };
  
  // Click img
  const handleImageClick = (index) => {
    setImagenSeleccionada(index);
  };
  
  // Condicion de imagen seleccionada
  const isImageSelected = (index) => {
    return index === imagenSeleccionada;
  };

  const changeValueArray = (arr, indexForChange, newValue) => {
    const newArray = arr.map((element, index) => {
      if (index === indexForChange) return newValue;
      return element
    })

    return newArray;
  }

  return (
    <ImageProvider>
      <div className={styles.marco} ref={ref}>
        {imagenes && imagenes.length > 0 && (
          <Cropper
            ref={cropperRef}
            className={styles.cropperCropBox}
            src={imagenes[0].url}
            guides={false}
            dragMode="none"
            responsive={true}
            autoCropArea={1}
            zoomTo={escala[imagenSeleccionada]}
            cropBoxResizable={false}
            zoomable={false}
            zoomOnTouch={false}
            wheelZoomRatio={0}
            cropBoxMovable={false}
          />
        )}
        <img
          onLoad={(e) => {
            setWidth(e.target.width);
            setHeight(e.target.height);
          }}
          className={styles.marcoImg}
          src={phoneImg}
          style={{
            zIndex: isPopupOpen ? 100000000 : -10000
          }}
          alt=""
        />

        <div className={styles.contenedorImgs}>
          {imagenes.map((imgData, index) => (
            <EditableImage
              key={imgData.url}
              src={imgData.url}
              index={index}
              referenciaImagenes={index}
              onDrop={handleDrop}
              onClick={() => handleImageClick(index)}
              isSelected={isImageSelected(index)}
              escala={escala[index]}
              translateX={imagenSeleccionada === index ? translateX : 0}
              translateY={imagenSeleccionada === index ? translateY : 0}
              className={isImageSelected(index) ? styles.selectedImage : ''}
              style={
                isImageSelected(index)
                  ? {
                    transform: `translate(${translateX}px, ${translateY}px) scale(${escala})`,
                  }
                  : {}
              }
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>

      <canvas
        ref={combinedImageRef}
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
        width="240"
        height="500"
      ></canvas>

      {/* <img src={combinedImageUrl} alt="Combined Image" /> */}

      <div className={styles.containerEditar}>
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <button
            className={styles.button}
            onClick={() => {
              if (isImageSelected(imagenSeleccionada)) {
                setEscala((estadoPrevio) => {
                  const newValue = estadoPrevio[imagenSeleccionada] + 0.3
                  const newState = changeValueArray(estadoPrevio, imagenSeleccionada, newValue)
                  return newState;
                });
              }
            }}
          >
            Zoom +
          </button>
          <button
            className={styles.button}
            onClick={() => {
              if (isImageSelected(imagenSeleccionada)) {
                setEscala((estadoPrevio) => {
                  const newValue = estadoPrevio[imagenSeleccionada] - 0.3
                  const newState = changeValueArray(estadoPrevio, imagenSeleccionada, newValue)

                  console.log(newState, "sacacorcho");
                  return newState;
                });
              }
            }}
          >
            Zoom -
          </button>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.container}>
          <button
            className={styles.button}
            onClick={() => {
              if (isImageSelected(imagenSeleccionada)) {
                setTranslateY(translateY - 5);
              }
            }}
          >
            Arriba
          </button>
          <button
            className={styles.button}
            onClick={() => {
              if (isImageSelected(imagenSeleccionada)) {
                setTranslateY(translateY + 5);
              }
            }}
          >
            Abajo
          </button>
          <button
            className={styles.button}
            onClick={() => {
              if (isImageSelected(imagenSeleccionada)) {
                setTranslateX(translateX + 5);
              }
            }}
          >
            {"=>"}
          </button>
          <button
            className={styles.button}
            onClick={() => {
              if (isImageSelected(imagenSeleccionada)) {
                setTranslateX(translateX - 5);
              }
            }}
          >
            {"<="}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className={styles.containerBotones}>
        <UploadWidget getImageData={handleAddImageShow} />
        <button onClick={TogglePopup}>Toggle</button>
        <button onClick={() => obtenerPrecio(id)}>Agregar al carrito</button>
      </div>

      <div style={{ display: "none"}}>
        {orderInfo.url && (
          <CheckoutPayment orderData={orderInfo}/>
        )}
      </div>

      {croppedImage && (
        <div>
          <img
            style={{
              display: "none",
              transform: `translate(${translateX[imagenSeleccionada]}px, ${translateY[imagenSeleccionada]}px)`,
            }}
            src={croppedImage}
            alt="Imagen recortada"
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </ImageProvider>
  );
};

export default Grilla1;
```

Comment: What are `GrillasContext` and `CartContext` defined as?

Comment: those are defined as context with some useful things, you can check it out here https://github.com/mxrtin-5/Makena/tree/main/makena